# Why does min_num in Django formsets lead to n+1 formset being rendered

Tags: python, django, formsets

In Django formsets (v. 1.9), there is an option min_num in the formset_factory function which specifies the minimum number of forms in the formset.

A view might look like this:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    msg = forms.CharField()

ExFormSet = formset_factory(ExampleForm, min_num=1)
ex_set =  ExFormSet()

context = {'ex_set': exp_set)
return render(request, 'app-name/test.html', context)
```

And the template might look like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <table>
    {{ ex_set }}
  </table>
</form>
```

However Django will always render one more form then given in the min_num argument.

Is the reason for this the general Django/Python design, starting to count at zero or am I misunderstanding the use of the min_num argument? In the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#validate-min) as I understand it, it says that the variable is just used for validation.

Comment: I presume its a typo in your question but in your context you set `ex_set` in the context to `exp_set` that isn't mentioned anywhere else

Answer (score 4):

One more form is from [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/formsets/#django.forms.formsets.formset_factory) keyword parameter whose default value is `1`. You can read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#django.forms.formsets.BaseFormSet) for more info on `extra` keyword parameter.

Comment: Yes I also found, that `extra` overrides the `min_num` parameter, in the sense that it determines the number of empty forms displayed at the beginning. But why does `min_num` show this behaviour if `extra` argument is not given?

Comment: @Jarno because `extra` have a default value of `1`, which is used if you do not pass it explicitly, try passing `extra=0` explicitly.

Comment: It seems that the number of number of empty forms is determined by `extra + minum`. E.g. if I pass `form_factory()` `extra=-2, min_num=5`, I get 3 empty forms. Still I don't understand the sense of two arguments that affect the same parameter.

Comment: Both serve different purposes, you are experimenting with empty forms, that is why you are being confused, you will understand if you experiment with editing existing instances using formset. `min_num` is for validation purposes, when formset is submitted to server it must have `min_num` forms in it. `extra` specifies how many extra forms should be created to create new instances of data along with existing instances you are editing. So if you do `MyFormSet(reques.POST['data of 5 objects'], extra=2)`, it will create 7 forms, 2 to create new objects, 5 to edit older.